# adb command to rotate the Android device (not emulator) display?

Tags: android

Is there any "adb command" or anything by which Android device (not emulator) display can get rotate i.e landscape to potrait and vice versa

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/a/14253321/603270

Comment: @AndroidDev Sorry, but the question got edited 2 hours **after** I posted my comment (Maverick did not stated "not emulator" but Chris Stratton did)... Watch the history before going on flames.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work. To change the screen orientation to lanscape :

`service call window 18 i32 1`

and to change it to portrait :

`service call window 18 i32 0`.

Comment: @ Thnaks vieuMa for quick reply but ..  it is displaying : Result: Parcel(00000000    '....') and screen orientation in not getting change :(

Comment: @Maverick Sorry about that... I just found [another post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11184503/android-emulator-orientation-change-through-emulator-console-or-adb) that could maybe help you ? If not, do you really have to use ADB ? [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/) is a really great emulator compared to standard emulator...

Comment: I am testing on real device .. there i have to perform this action during  one test run

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution:

```bash
adb shell content insert --uri content://settings/system --bind name:s:user_rotation --bind value:i:1
```

- `1` at the end means that the device rotation will be set to "landscape".
- `0` - "portrait".
- `2` - "reversed portrait".
- `3` - "*other* landscape".

Sources:

- https://gist.github.com/whunter/832c844db80dda873a81,
- https://www.declarecode.com/code-solutions/shell/adb-shell-command-to-rotate-screen.